# Setting up the logger in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, logging

I'm trying to figure out how to use the logger with rails 3. I need to log to a file not have it in the console, but I just can't figure out how to set it up and then, how to write something to that log. I tried the rails docs but they didn't really make it clear.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

By default, Rails should be logging to an environment-specific log file in your project's `log` directory. It will be called either `test.log`, `development.log`, or `production.log` depending on which environment you're running in.

You can log directly to Rails' logger using the `Rails.logger` object:

```
Rails.logger.info "My info message"
Rails.logger.debug "My debugging message"
Rails.logger.warn "My warning message"
```

Rails used to use [Ruby's standard logging class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/logger/rdoc/index.html), but it now uses [`ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/BufferedLogger.html). (The official [Ruby on Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html) are incorrect when they say "Rails makes use of Ruby’s standard logger to write log information").

Comment: I believe it's using ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger ... just check out Rails.logger.class

Comment: @Duke You are absolutely correct. Looks like the official Rails Guides are incorrect.