# Custom logger in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to have a custom logger for my application, which of course logs to a different file, someone asked a question: [Setting up the logger in rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6019583/setting-up-the-logger-in-rails-3)

But I want to have a logger which I can call with my own class name like:

```
StatusLogger.info "something happend!!!"
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Why would you want to do this, its much better to have one log file and parse it to find events.

Comment: I don't know, I guess thats a good point, but like I have these rake tasks that are run via cron and like I wanted to just log when they happened so I can go back and look at when they took place and the status of the tasks that ran. What would be a good way to address this?

Comment: Wont cron email the output of the cronjob to root? Anyway, this seems like a fine way to deal with the situation at hand. Cronjobs are tough to diagnose and manage when you are used to dealing with webapps. Maybe ask on serverfault?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could do that with this code

```
logfile = File.open('/path/to/log.log', 'a')  
StatusLogger = Logger.new(logfile)
StatusLogger.info 'Hello World!'
```

And you would most likely configure this in an initializer file, or you could do it in an environment file if you wanted.

Comment: Hey Devin, thanks, when I try this it seems to work but there is nothing in the log file, thoughts?

Answer (score 13):

You mean, like having in application.rb:

```
StatusLogger = ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger.new(Rails.root.join('log/status.log'))
```

Comment: This code blob in an initializer called config/initializer/log.rb # for instance

Comment: Note: You can put this anywhere in your application, not just in `application.rb`, as long as you remember to assign it to a variable (instead of a constant as shown here)