# undefined method `debug' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging

for a couple of days, I've been having following issue:

in all my models, i get `"undefined method`debug' for nil:NilClass"` when it runs

```
logger.debug "whatever"
```

Adding Rails. in front of logger.debug solves the issue but I'd like to find the cause.

I have no clue where to search. I'm running rails 3.2.8 and the only gem I recently installed is friendly_id

thanks.

Comment: more info regarding logger http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6019583/setting-up-the-logger-in-rails-3

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't answer my question: why am I suddenly forced to add "Rails." before logger.debug every time I use it. It worked without it before. It's not dramatic but annoying...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to the fact that I added the actionview helpers in my model:

```
  include ActionView::Helpers
```

I don't know the reason but it's the cause...
To avoid having to add Rails in front of all my logger lines, I then added this line in the models having the Helpers included:

```
  logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
```